# If a beam of particles travelling at high speeds/ has high energy and decay is induced in the beam will the particles produced also be high energy

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

If we have a high energy beam of for example Beryllium 9 (this element emits neutrons when subject to high intensity radiation) and we hit it with high energy gamma radiation will the neutrons emitted also be of high energy.

Comment: One a practical note: I've work on $\vec{\gamma}+ \vec{e}^+ \rightarrow \gamma + e^+$ (for beam polarimetry), and the inbound light was from an ordinary laser. Since the positrons were at 28 GeV, they were gamma rays in the COM frame. Much easier than creating a high intensity polarized gamma source.

Comment: @JEB A high five from another Compton polarimeter user. Was your polarimetry for the muon $g-2$? I vaguely remember 28 GeV as the magic energy for that muon storage ring.

Comment: DESY/HERMES, back in the day. We had a circular polarized laser and linear polarized laser. One had a rate asymmetry, the other a left right asymmetry.